# firebaseのruleの記載においてchildの中にロケーション変数を使用したい

Tags: firebase

いつもお世話になっております。
現在firebaseでチャットソフトを作成しているのですが、バックエンド側の処理で思ったようにいかずつまづいてしまいました。

データベース上のチャットルームに読み込み権限と書き込み権限を付けたのですが、ruleから参照する方法が分からず質問させて頂きました。

rule

```json
 {
   
   "rules": {
     "rooms" : {
       ".read": "auth != null",
         ".write": "auth != null",
         "$room_id" :{
                    ".read": "root.child('rooms').child($room_id).child('read').val()=='true'",
                    ".write": "root.child('rooms').child($room_id).child('write').val()=='true'",
         }
     }
   }
 }
```

データベース

```json
         {
          
      "rooms" : {
        "-ROOM_ID_1" : {
          "admin" : false,
          "img_upload" : false,
          "messages" : {
            "-MB-NAtBV1ybNEUM-DVS" : {
              "name" : "hoge.",
              "text" : "テスト"
            }
          },
          "read" : true,
          "room_name" : "部屋1",
          "write" : true
        },
        "-ROOM_ID_2" : {
          "admin" : false,
          "img_upload" : false,
          "messages" : {
            "-MB-BcDIyABa7Ngw23IM" : {
              "name" : "hoge",
              "text" : "テスト"
            },
            "-MB-NPjk4xd0h_JZTUjG" : {
              "name" : "hoge",
              "text" : "テスト"
            }
          },
          "read" : true,
          "room_name" : "部屋2",
          "write" : true
     }
    }
 }
```

ruleからデータベースのroom内のwriteを参照したいのですが、参照できず困っています。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
ちょっと改良したため、こんな感じになりました。

**データベース**

```js
{
  "admin-users" : {
    "9k3Uf---------------" : true
  },
  "black-list" : {
    "MAtSa-------------" : true
  },
  "rooms" : {
    "-MB3l-----------" : {
      "admin" : false,
      "author" : "",
      "img_upload" : false,
      "messages" : {
        "-MB3nu----------" : {
          "name" : "Haru Haru",
          "photoUrl" : "",
          "text" : "テスト"
        }
      },
      "photoUrl" : "",
      "read" : true,
      "room_name" : "部屋1",
      "write" : true
    },
    "-MB3m---------------" : {
      "admin" : false,
      "author" : "",
      "img_upload" : false,
      "photoUrl" : "",
      "read" : true,
      "room_name" : "部屋2",
      "write" : false
    }
  }
}
```

**ルール**

```js
{  
  "rules": {
    "admin-users" : {
      ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('black-list').child(auth.uid).exists()",
      ".write": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    },
    "black-list" : {
      ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('black-list').child(auth.uid).exists()",
      ".write": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    },
    "rooms" : {
      ".read": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth != null && !root.child('black-list').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        "$room_id" :{
                    ".read": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth != null && !root.child('black-list').child(auth.uid).exists() && data.child('read').val()==true",
              ".write": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth != null && !root.child('black-list').child(auth.uid).exists() && data.child('write').val()==true"
        }
    }
  }
}
```